# Issue while loading/serving tensorflow model in java using estimators

Tags: java, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I used the census data and created a wide and deep model using the estimators api in tensorflow. While loading the model in Java, there seems to be an error which doesn't let the model to be loaded. Exception looks like

```
Exception in thread "main" org.tensorflow.TensorFlowException: Op type not 
registered 'SparseFeatureCross' in binary running on gmalhotra-mba-2.local. 
Make sure the Op and Kernel are registered in the binary running in this 
process.
at org.tensorflow.SavedModelBundle.load(Native Method)
at org.tensorflow.SavedModelBundle.load(SavedModelBundle.java:39)
at deeplearning.DeepLearningTest.main(DeepLearningTest.java:32)
```

Please find the python code below used for saving the model: 
https://gist.github.com/gaganmalhotra/cd6a5898b9caf9005a05c8831a9b9153

Java code used is as follows:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
          try (SavedModelBundle b = SavedModelBundle.load("/Users/gagandeep.malhotra/Documents/SampleTF_projects/temporaryModel/1510624417/", "serve")) {


    Session sess = b.session();

                //Create the input sensor 
                  float[][] mat=new float[1][1];
                  mat[0]=new float[]{0.5f};

                // create tensors specific to inputs ....

                Tensor<?> x = (Tensor<?>) Tensor.create(mat);

                //run the model 
                float[][] y = sess.runner()
                        .feed("input", x)
                        .fetch("output")
                        .run()
                        .get(0)
                        .copyTo(new float[1][1]);               

               //print the result
                System.out.println(y[0][0]);
}
```

PS : Tensorflow version used: 1.3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use operations in the `tf.contrib` module, they are not considered to be experimental, thus are not part of the [stable TensorFlow API](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/version_compat) and aren't included in other language distributions.

However, in TensorFlow 1.4 and above you can explicitly load the shared library in Java using [`TensorFlow.loadLibrary()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/java/reference/org/tensorflow/TensorFlow.html#loadLibrary(java.lang.String)).

To do that, first you need to find the location of the shared library that contains the implementation of the `tf.contrib` operation you're interested in. In this case it seems like it's `tf.contrib.layers`, so you'd do something like this:

```
python -c "import tensorflow; print(tensorflow.contrib.layers.__path__)"
```

Which would print something like:

```
['/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers']
```

Then you'd find all the shared libraries in that path using something like:

```
find /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers -name "*.so"
```

Which would be something like:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/ops/_sparse_feature_cross_op.so
```

Alright, now you have that library, you can load it in Java using:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TensorFlow.loadLibrary("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/ops/_sparse_feature_cross_op.so");

    // And now load the model etc.
}
```

Caveats:

- If you want to run on a different machine, you'd want to package the `.so` file above with your program and adjust the call to `TensorFlow.loadLibrary()` appropriately.
- Make sure you're using the same TensorFlow version for Python and Java (1.4)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much @ash for the workaround ill to use it the way you mentioned and get back!