# how to use tensorflow.contrib in java?

Tags: java, tensorflow

I'm using a model tensor_forest in java land, and run into this exception:

`: org.tensorflow.TensorFlowException: Op type not registered 'DecisionTreeResourceHandleOp' in binary running on MyMachine. Make sure the Op and Kernel are registered in the binary running in this process.`

anyone can help me with this type of error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issue while loading/serving tensorflow model in java using estimators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47276624/issue-while-loading-serving-tensorflow-model-in-java-using-estimators)