# Using ops from Tensorflow.contrb on Windows via Java API

Tags: java, tensorflow

I would like to load an `op` from `tf.contrib`, specifically "_beam_search_ops". I use Tensorflow 1.6 from Maven.

Following the answer at [Issue while loading/serving tensorflow model in java using estimators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47276624/issue-while-loading-serving-tensorflow-model-in-java-using-estimators/47277367#47277367) , I'm able to do so on Ubuntu 17.10.

The code looks like so:

```
TensorFlow.loadLibrary("_beam_search_ops.so");
```

Then I try to do the same in Windows 10 with code

```
TensorFlow.loadLibrary("_beam_search_ops.dll");
```

And it fails with

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: D:\Users\ALEXAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\deep_api_plugin\_beam_search_ops.dll not found
    at org.tensorflow.TensorFlow.loadLibrary(TensorFlow.java:47)
```

So what is the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

While I was writing and researching the question, I've stumbled on the solution.

In order to resolve the problem, a `_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd` file should be copied to the folder where `_beam_search_ops.dll` resides. I understand that this is also some kind of `dll`, but do not understand why it is necessary for Windows and not for Ubuntu. If anyone happens to know, please enlighten me.

Also I understand that this sort of additional information should be provided in a comment to the original answer, but unfortunately I do not have enough reputation to comment and thought this answer could help someone.

Edit: I was too quick to celebrate. With this answer a library is loaded without exception, but the model cannot seem to use it, failing with

```
Exception in thread "main" org.tensorflow.TensorFlowException: Op type not registered 'GatherTree' in binary running on DESKTOP-EB6GIDR. Make sure the Op and Kernel are registered in the binary running in this process.
    at org.tensorflow.SavedModelBundle.load(Native Method)
    at org.tensorflow.SavedModelBundle.load(SavedModelBundle.java:39)
```

Search for answer should continue.