# Executing frozen tensorflow graph that uses tensorflow.contrib.resampler using c_api.h

Tags: c, tensorflow

I have a frozen tensorflow graph (.pb format) that contains a call to tensorflow.contrib.resampler, which must be loaded and executed in a C application using `c_api.h`.

I am able to succesfully load and execute this graph from python if I call:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.contrib.resampler
```

before I load the graph.

However, I cannot find how to do the same using the C api, which leads to a failure with the following message:

```
Failed to process frame with No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'Resampler'
with these attrs.  Registered devices: [CPU,GPU], Registered kernels:
<no registered kernels>
```

How can I instruct tensorflow that this op exists using the C api?

Comment: Looking at the code, it seems that the operation is located in a [separate binary called `_resampler_ops.so`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.8/tensorflow/contrib/resampler/python/ops/resampler_ops.py#L28). No surprise it cannot find it -- you will need to load this library first.

Comment: Surprisingly, this binary does not exist in my installation (tensorflow-gpu 1.8.0 installed through pip on windows), yet the python version is able to load and run the graph. That means the op exists and can be loaded iff I can figure out how to do that in C.

Answer (score 2):

(This is very similar to [this other StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47277367/6708503) talking about the same thing, but for Java)

When you use operations in the `tf.contrib` module, they are not considered to be experimental, thus are not part of the [stable TensorFlow API](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/version_compat) and aren't included in other language distributions.

However, you can explicitly load the shared library in C using [`TF_LoadLibrary`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/dcb10b1d557168646204239bea6ca5bf1abc40a3/tensorflow/c/c_api.h#L1526).

To do that, first you need to find the location of the shared library that contains the implementation of the `tf.contrib` operation you're interested in. In this case it seems like it's `tf.contrib.resampler`, so you'd do something like this:

```
python -c "import tensorflow; print(tensorflow.contrib.resampler.__path__)"
```

Which would print something like:

```
['/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/resampler']
```

Then you'd find all the shared libraries in that path using something like:

```
find /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/resampler -name "*.so"
```

Which would be something like:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/resampler/python/ops/_resampler_ops.so
```

Alright, now you have that library, you can load it in C using:

```
TF_Status* status = TF_NewStatus();
TF_LoadLibrary("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/resampler/python/ops/_resampler_ops.so", status);
if (TF_GetCode(status) != TF_OK) {
  // Log/fail, details in TF_Message(status)
}
TF_DeleteStatus(status);
```

Caveats:

- If you want to run on a different machine, you'd want to package the `.so` file above with your program and adjust the call to `TF_LoadLibrary` appropriately.
- Make sure you're using the same TensorFlow version for Python and C
- **Windows**: For Windows, the build is currently (till TensorFlow 1.8 at least) different and all operations are statically compiled into a single native library included with the pip package, but not with the C API release binaries. So, there is no DLL corresponding to these contrib operations that you can load.

Hope that helps.