# Not found: Op type not registered 'Resampler' are registered in the binary in running in this process

Tags: c++, tensorflow, ubuntu-16.04

system: ubuntu16.04

tensorflow: 1.7.0
I have built my libtensorflow_cc.so successfully. When I load my pb file( I used tf.contrib.resampler here) in the graph, error shows up as create graph wrong: Not found: Op type not registered 'Resampler' in binary running on xxx. Make sure the Op and Kernel are registered in the binary running in this process.

I have looked up similar questions like this [Executing frozen tensorflow graph that uses tensorflow.contrib.resampler using c_api.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50475320/executing-frozen-tensorflow-graph-that-uses-tensorflow-contrib-resampler-using-c)
I find the _resampler_ops.so and try to load it using TF_LoadLibrary, but it fails and the error remains. The tensorflow for python and c++ is 1.7.0

```
Session *session;
Status status = NewSession(SessionOptions(), &session);
if (!status.ok())
{
    cout << "create session wrong: "<< status.ToString() << endl;
    return -1;
}
GraphDef graph_def;
//read model:
if (!ReadBinaryProto(Env::Default(), graph_name, &graph_def).ok())
{
    cout << "Read model(pb) failed!" << endl;
    return -1;
}
status = session->Create(graph_def);
TF_Status* status_1 = TF_NewStatus();
TF_LoadLibrary("/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/resampler/python/ops/_resampler_ops.so", status_1);
if (TF_GetCode(status_1) != TF_OK) {
    cout << "load lib wrong" << endl;
}
TF_DeleteStatus(status_1);
if (!status.ok())
{
    cout << "create graph wrong: " << status.ToString() << endl;
    return -1;
}
    cout<<"load graph done!"<<endl;
```